# simulate cushion without changing overall shape

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm working on a modular sofa project with a lot of different cushion geometries. In the past I've used the cloth simulation with pressure and some clever weight painting to create the wrinkles and softness I needed for the sofa. However, my client now wants to see something more rectilinear and inflating the sofa will be too blobby. I was wondering if there's some way to simulate the wrinkling without changing the overall shape too much?

I'm relatively new to blender (I do most of my modeling in Rhino), but I was hoping I might be able to essentially do the following:

1. model the inflation, creating the wrinkles
2. smooth the inflated cushion to remove the wrinkles
3. calculate the offset between the wrinkled and unwrinkled cushion
4. apply offset to my uninflated cushion

If someone has an idea on how I could accomplish the above or a better solution I'd love to know. I would really like to avoid hand-sculpting or applying normal maps as I have so much geometry to work with! Thanks

Comment: Sketches and/or images how it should look would help

Comment: maybe inflate a cushion, bake the normals, and use these normals for a more rectilinear cushion?